# Is ペンキ塗り立て a common expression for "Wet Paint"?

Tags: pragmatics

Is ペンキ塗り立て a common expression? If not, what will be a typical sign warning of **wet paint**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's the most common expression on Japanese "wet paint" signs. You can buy stickers and tapes with ペンキ塗り立て.

[image]

Related:

- [What kind of verbs can the suffix たて （立て） attach to?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12269/5010)
- [What is the たて in 取れる+たて?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5325/5010)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is- Allow me to explain.
～立て（たて）is a piece of grammar added to the stem of verbs to signify that they have been freshly or very recently done.

「習いたての単語を使う」→ to use a recently learned word

「焼きたてのパンを食べる」→to eat freshly baked bread

Therefore, the verb 塗る（ぬる） or to paint, being that it has ～立て attached, expresses the freshness of the paint job.