# Meaning of したて after a する-verb

Tags: grammar, meaning

I found this sentence in a fiction I'm reading and am confused about what したて means after 弟子入り. Context: He is talking to a young merchant who reminded him of himself when he was younger.

> なんだか、親戚の行商人の元に弟子入りしたての頃を思い出したのだった。

Although I understand the gist of the sentence, I've never seen したて as a form of する. I thought maybe it might be 仕立て from 仕立てる to meaning training? So 弟子入り仕立て would mean something along the lines of "Apprentice in training"? Is this correct or am I interpreting it wrong?

Comment: related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/what-is-the-%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a6-in-%e5%8f%96%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a6

Comment: @Ringil Thanks, that post makes a lot of sense. What I'm getting from this is that 弟子入りしたて would mean something akin to "to have just finished their apprenticeship"?

Comment: I think it's "just started apprenticeship"